# Error in downloading data from bloomberg via library "rbbg"

Tags: r, bloomberg, rjava

I have a R code to download data from Bloomberg regularly. It had worked perfectly fine since 4 months ago untill very recently. The library "rbbg" is still loaded successfully and as I generate connection, the message seems ok:

```
R version 2.15.2 (2012-10-26) 
rJava Version 0.9-3 
Rbbg Version 0.4-155 
Java environment initialized successfully.
Adding S:/Projects/RCDS/APIv3/JavaAPI/v3.4.6.6/bin/blpapi-3.4.6-6.jar to Java classpath
Bloomberg API Version 3.4.6.6
```

However, as I started to download data from Bloomberg using tick(...), the process stopped with an error message:

```
Error in .jcall("RJavaTools", "Ljava/lang/Object;", "invokeMethod", cl,  : 
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: Session Not Started
```

I cannot tell what is wrong based on this error message. It can be either in rJava or Bloomberg API or even somewhere else. I suspect some verion conflict due to some update but I am not sure. Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Maybe your subscription to Bloomberg expired?

Comment: I can stkll login Bloomberg via terminal. I guess it is not the problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience I think you need to be logged on to Bloomberg (via the terminal/GUI) already for the API to work.